# Missing Colors Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: pi-2

I just got my Raspberry Pi 2 in the mail today and upon installing Raspian and booting it up it appears as if my coloration is messed up. It is not inverted colors but perhaps missing colors such as red. When I load it up the default background image appears as if its a blue raspberry with brighter green leaves. I am displaying it on my TV with an HDMI cable, and I know its not my TV given I've never had problems with it displaying HDMI feeds.

Any one have an idea? This is also fresh out of the box so I haven't tampered with anything.

[image: Startx View]

I'm also getting the error below, as you can see from the screenshot,

```
GBBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject
```

but I've read that it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I see some red in the top left corner of the error dialog. So it seems the red color is not completely absent. How does the rainbow-colored square look in the beginning of the boot process? And the four raspberries above the boot messages?

Comment: Looks like Red and Blue are getting interchanged. Not sure why it's happening though.

Answer (score -1):

Your error message indicates the Policykit Authentication Agent must be disabled.  This is corrected by running the following command in LXTerminal:

lxsession-edit
This will bring up the Desktop Session Settings dialog box.
Under Automatically Started Applications tab:

Uncheck: LXPolKit

Click OK, Close out, Reboot.